# linking data from different json objects in jsrender

Tags: javascript, json, relation, jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to link the data from foos and selectedFoos. I wish to list the selectedFoos and show the name from the foos object. The fooid in the selectedFoos would be linked to the foos id.

EDIT: I dont want to alter the structure of foos or selectedFoos.

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/marabutt/Fz4Kd/8/)

Html, Template

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script id="content_gen" type="x-jsrender">
    <ul> {^{for sf}} 
         <li > {{: fooid}} - {{: code}} {{foo.name}} </li>   
         {{/for}} 
    </ul>
</script>
```

JS

```
var foos = [{
    "id": 1,
        "name": "a"
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "name": "b"
}, {
    "id": 3,
        "name": "c"
}];
var selectedFoos = [{
    "fooid": 1,
        "code": "z"
}, {
    "fooid": 3,
        "code": "w"
}];

var app = {
    sf: selectedFoos,
    f: foos
};
var templ = $.templates("#content_gen");
templ.link("#content", app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's answer is nice. But since you are using JsViews - you may want to data-link so you bind to the name and code values. Interesting case here, where you want to bind while in effect traversing a lookup...

So there are several possible approaches. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/7Jwrd/2/ that takes a modified version of Scott's fiddle, with a slightly simplified converter approach, but in addition shows using nested {{for}} loops, as well as two different examples of using helper functions.

You can modify the `name` or the `code`, and see how the update works. You'll see that `code` updates in all cases, but to get the `name` to update is more tricky given the lookup.

You'll see that in the following two approaches, even the data-binding to the name works too.

**Nested for loops**

Template:

```
{^{for sf }}
    {^{for ~root.f ~fooid=fooid ~sf=#data}}
        {{if id === ~fooid}}
            <li>{^{:name}} - {^{:~sf.code}} </li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

**Helper returning the lookup object**

Helper:

```
function getFoo(fooid) {
    var r = $.grep(foos, function (o) {
        return o.id == fooid;
    })
    return r[0] || {name: ""};
}
```

Template:

```
{^{for sf}}
    <li>{^{:~getFoo(fooid).name}} - {^{:code}} </li>
{{/for}}
```

See the many topics and samples here

- http://www.jsviews.com

such as the following:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#converters
- http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers
- http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag
- http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/for-and-if

Comment: Thanks Boris. There are a feast of solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a [view converter](http://www.jsviews.com/#converters) to lookup the name by id.

Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Fz4Kd/11/

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script id="content_gen" type="x-jsrender">
    <ul> {^{for sf}}
        <li>{{id2name:fooid ~root.f }} - {{: code}} </li>   
    {{/for}} 
        </ul>
</script>
```

js

```
var app = {
    sf: selectedFoos,
    f: foos
};

$.views.converters("id2name", function (id, foos) {
    var r = $.grep(foos, function (o) {
        return o.id == id;
    })
    return (r.length > 0) ? r[0].name : '';
});

var templ = $.templates("#content_gen");
templ.link("#content", app);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over `selectedFoos` and lookup the name with `fooid` by iterating over `foos`. Then combine that data before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNameById(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++)
        if (foos[i].id == id)
            return foos[i].name;
    return '';
}
```

This function will return the `name` when given the `id`.

Usage:

```
alert(getNameById(2)); // alerts "b"
```